# Excel VBA - Run-time error '53': File not found. But file was found

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that pulls data from a folder full of .txt documents.
Last week Friday, it worked. Nothing changed. This week Monday, I get a Run-time error '53': File not found.

What's interesting, is that when I click "Debug" it highlights a line in my code, and when I mouse over the 'sFile' variable, it tells me the name of the file that it apparently can't find... but it could only know the name of it if it found it... And yes, I've verified, that file does exist.

The Excel sheet is in H:\My Documents\Loma CW3 Reports\

The data .txt files are in H:\My Documents\Loma CW3 Reports\Product Statistics\

The first 3 files that it should be pulling are:

```
- PR20180912T153019.txt
- PR20180913T070005.txt
- PR20180913T153002.txt
```

Like mentioned above, when I'm debugging the code and mouse-over "sFile" in the line "Open sFile For Input As #1", it tells me:

```
sFile = "PR20180912T153019.txt"
```

Which it could only know if it was successfully scanning the folder since I don't hardcode any of those file names in.

I have tried removing that file, renaming the file to a word like 'apple', checked to see if it became read-only (nope). I'm thrown for a loop here, because it worked as is last week, and nothing changed from when I opened it up this week and tried it.

Code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Dim myFile As String
Dim text As String, textLine As String
Dim sFile As String, rowTarget As Long

rowTarget = 2

' myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

sFile = Dir("H:\My Documents\Loma CW3 Reports\Product Statistics\" & "*.txt*")
Do Until sFile = ""
    Open sFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textLine
        text = text & textLine
    Loop
    Close #1

    Do stuff here

    rowTarget = rowTarget + 1
    sFile = Dir()
    text = ""
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Put `Debug.Print CurDir` right above `Open sFile`. Are you in the correct directory?  You really should be using a full path with `Open` (and also using `FreeFile` instead of hard coded file numbers).

Comment: I'd vote for a timing issue. The file was created some (milli)seconds after your code was run

Comment: @Comintern I could be misunderstanding you, but aren't I using a full path with Open? sFile = Dir("H:\My Documents\Loma CW3 Reports\Product Statistics\PR20180912T153019.txt.") followed by the "open sFile" line. I did the Debug.Print CurDir, it reads "H:\My Documents"

Comment: Ummm... No. `Dir` doesn't return the full path. You said yourself that `sFile` had a value of `"PR20180912T153019.txt"`.

Comment: Oh, I guess you're right. duh. haha
I tried copying that "PR20180912T153019.txt" file to H:\My Documents, and then it worked for that single document. 
So something is messing up my directories then? I did a Save As for the Excel doc, into the same folder it currently was. Now I'm getting CurDir = "H:\My Documents\Loma CW3 Reports"

Comment: Nothing is "messing your directories up". You just need to open `"H:\My Documents\Loma CW3 Reports\Product Statistics\" & sFile `

Comment: That was it :) Weird that it worked last week and not this week though. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up specifying directory as a separate variable and appended the sFile name to it when opening the file.

```
Dim directory As String

directory = "H:\My Documents\Loma CW3 Reports\Product Statistics\"
sFile = Dir(directory & "*.txt*")

Do Until sFile = ""
    Open (directory & sFile) For Input As #1
    blah blah blah
```

Thanks @comintern

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

1. Go to **File explorer**, tab **View**, click on **Options**.
2. Go to tab **View**, and uncheck *Hide extensions for known file types*.
3. Now you will see in your file explorer the filename becomes
   `"PR20180912T153019.txt.txt"`.

Explanation: you added `".txt"` to the filename, which was not required, because it is a known file type.

Comment: @user10186832: It very much is an answer. And it’s totally fine to answer old questions that have already been answered. That said, this would be a far more useful answer if the author explained _why_ they feel this solution improves upon the OP’s solution, or under what circumstances this would be preferred.

Comment: @MT1: the problem is that the provided answer is a workaround solution for a mistake. The user should solve the mistake instead of making the problem even worse.