# Run time error 53 file not found for some files in directory

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a program to prompt the user to select a folder filled with .txt files and then extract information.

There are some files it cannot find and gives me a run time error 53 file not found despite the file being in the folder.

Debugging points to the 'Open MyFile For Input As #1' line.

If I specify the file path and run the macro it extracts the information so the file path is correct.

I looked at this solution

[Excel VBA - Run-time error '53': File not found. But file was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307106/excel-vba-run-time-error-53-file-not-found-but-file-was-found)

basically specifying a directory then trying to read each file from that directory but I get the same error.

Here is the original code to prompt the user to select a folder than read each file in the folder.

```
Sub read()
'PURPOSE: Send All Data From Text File To A String Variable

    Dim TextFile As Integer
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileContent As String


    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String

'Opens a file dialog box for user to select a folder

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .Show
       MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
       Err.Clear
    End With


'create a new object for files in that folder and apply the for/loop as below
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.getFolder(MyFolder)

    Dim fls As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    For Each fls In objFolder.Files

'File Path of Text File

    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\" & fls.Name, vbReadOnly)

'Determine the next file number available for use by the FileOpen function

    TextFile = FreeFile


'Open the text file

    Open MyFile For Input As #1
```

Answer (score 0):

by using the line you actually stripping the file name of its path

```
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\" & fls.Name, vbReadOnly)
```

simply make it

```
MyFile = MyFolder & "\" & fls.Name
```